# Bash script to execute a binary file for a time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, intel-edison

I have two binary files that I want to execute one after the other, the thing is that I want to execute both for one minute. I have the following bash code:

```
./file_1
./file_2
```

but I do not know how to only run it for a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a one-liner using the [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) command

```
$ timeout 60 binary-1; timeout 60 binary-2
```

In this case, the format is:

```
timeout duration command
```

Where duration defaults to seconds, or also could be used 1m (1 minutes), from the man:

```
duration is a floating point number followed by an optional unit:

‘s’ for seconds (the default)
‘m’ for minutes
‘h’ for hours
‘d’ for days
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a portable solution - run the binaries in the background, and kill them after a minute:

```
for file in "file_1" "file_2"; do
    "./$file" &
    file_pid=$!

    sleep 60

    kill "$file_pid"
done
```

The `&` operator starts a background job, and the special variable `$!` contains the PID of the last job. The loop is optional. We can use it to reduce duplicated code.